# ArcGIS Web Application wont load on mobile device

Tags: android, cordova, gis, arcgis

I have created an app with ArcGIS Web App Builder and when hosted on a local server it works fine, but when I build the app using Apache Cordova and load the APK file onto the phone and install it. That app will not load on the phone and stay on the splash screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an obvious question, but is the original Arcgis app based on esri web-server applications or do you have your own esri server? In previous conversations with esri, they have indicated that apps must run through (or are ultimately controlled by) their servers and cannot be stand-alone without a server account. Someone on stackoverflow can add more insight, but one test of this is to see if the whole web package will run without a web connection. Usually, you will find that basemaps,and other embedded files interact with the esri mothership.

Comment: It is based off of everything downloaded in the .zip file that was created by WebAppBuilder. You do not need any association with the arcgis server or online to create the app. So you believe I need to have it running on a arc server for it to work? If its on my windows server it works fine for me.

Comment: Have you been able to run all the map files without an Internet connection?

Comment: This is exactly my point...there are some resources that are resident on the esri servers. Someone else on this list may have a work-around for this...but basically, I have found that esri has many ties to their online builds, so that if a build does work, there will probably be some missing assets (basemaps, etc.). Just my experience thus far.

Comment: Yeah whenever I try to open the app if it is not running on a server it does not go past the splash screen, but if you find anything out that would be great!